# Asking to change my title from intern

Tags: united-states, internship, title

I am currently a paid interned doing software development and prototyping. This is my third year doing this. My first year I had a mentor, however he is no longer with the company. Since then I have been continuing to do work for the company and solving problems that come up on my own. They are even planning on selling a product that I prototyped and designed mostly on my own. Given all this, I no longer think the word "internship" applies to my current work situation.

I will not be with the company for much longer because I need to move (my boss knows this) and I will need to find another job. I would like my title changed from "Intern" to something along the lines of "junior software developer" since it will help when applying for my next job and would more accurately describe what I do. I do not intend to ask for increased pay.

Is such a change actually going to be worthwhile for my job prospects? If so, what do I need to keep in mind when deciding (such as legal obligations the company may have if I am not considered an intern, or other reasons my employer may not wish to grant me this).

Comment: As a developer myself, I'd push to be a "Software Developer".  Your selling point on a future interview is this system you designed and prototyped from scratch, without a mentor breathing over you.  Then your company turned around and was able to SELL your ideas.  People that can do that are not "Junior Developers" in my book.

Comment: @raterus totally agreed, if its just a promotion not coming with a raise, I dont see why they wouldnt do this favor to the OP.

Comment: Are you still at university?  Is this 3 separate internships or are you actually an full time employee with the  title of intern?

Comment: @Neuromancer Still in university. I work full time, when not in school and part time when attending

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Given all this, I no longer think the word "internship" applies to my
>   current work situation.

Agreed, at this point you are not an intern IMHO.

> Is such a change actually going to be worthwhile for my job prospects?

Based on my experience, if you can get your title bumped up to Jr versus Intern **it should definitely help your job prospects and your next starting salary**.

It is not painful on your current employers part to help you in this way, so I would just have a nice conversation with your boss to see what their thoughts are on the subject.

*Most likely* you will get your wish.

Answer (score -1):

If you were producing useful work for the company, you were not an intern (under US law, anyway).

If they're selling a product based on your work, I would also suggest that you're not a 'Junior' developer either. Ask to be a Software Engineer/Developer or similar. You do real work, you need a real title. I don't think you'll have a problem.

Comment: _If you were producing useful work for the company, you were not an intern (under US law, anyway)._ No you are wrong. There is no such rule in USA

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson actualy the DOJ does set some strict rules about internships they are ment to be training positions.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson actually there is.. well sort of. Specifically US law requires that they can't have interns producing useful work without paying them. Paid internship positions are allowed to be used for actual work.